# Load react spa in aem component modal

Tags: reactjs, single-page-application, aem

We have AEM weekend react spa. There is a requirement in AEM component on click of a button we have to load this SPA site inside the modal pop up. How can we achieve it.

I have tried to load using normal javascript but it would not load the spa as normal site inside modal rather it just loads the html content of it which would not fulfill my requirement. Any solutions for the same.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.